# ANTLR4 - Match values over 9?

Tags: regex, antlr4

So, I've been working again on my assembler, this time I'm hanging with the floating-point registers. Basically, there are 32 fp registers. So, I want to match them, if I write F0, F1, F2, ..., F31. I wrote following into my lexer:

```
REG
 : ('R0'|'r0')
 | ('AT'|'at')
 | ('v'[0-1]|'V'[0-1])
 | ('a'[0-3]|'A'[0-3])
 | ('t'[0-9]|'T'[0-9])
 | ('s'[0-9]|'S'[0-8])
 | ('k'[0-1]|'K'[0-1])
 | ('GP'|'gp')
 | ('SP'|'sp')
 | ('FP'|'fp')
 | ('ra'|'RA')
 | ('f'[0-31]|'F'[0-31])+
 ;
```

Basically, every register here worked without any problems. But F0-F31 seems not to work. I tested it out and noticed, that it only matches F0-F3 but not any higher. This was quite obvious in that moment and I couldn't find out how I would match values which are over 10. I also tried some workarounds like adding more [0-9] behind the others, but that didn't help, as it then would match later values like F36 or F39. So, any idea how I could handle this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `[0-31]` matches the `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` or `1` (again). To emphasise: regular expression classes do not match numeric values, but (text) characters.

To match F0, F1, F2, ..., F31 (and f0, f1, f2, ..., f31), do something like this:

```
FREG
 : [fF] ( [0-9]         // matches f0..f9 (and F0..F9) 
        | [1-2] [0-9]   // matches f10..f29 (and F10..F29)
        | '3' [01]      // matches f30 or f31 (and F30 or F31)
        )
 ;
```

Your complete `REG` rule could be written as follows:

```
REG
 : [rR] '0'
 | 'AT' | 'at'
 | [vV] [01]
 | [aA] [0-3]
 | [tT] [0-9]
 | [sS] [0-9]
 | [kK] [01]
 | 'GP' | 'gp'
 | 'SP' | 'sp'
 | 'FP' | 'fp'
 | 'RA' | 'ra'
 | [fF] ( [0-9] | [1-2] [0-9] | '3' [01] )
 ;
```

Note that `[01]` and `[0-1]` match the same: either `'0'` or `'1'`. Also be aware that `'ra' | 'RA'` does not match `'Ra'`. If you want `'Ra'` and `'rA'` to match as well, write it like this: `[rR] [aA]`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now everything works perfectly.